# Mac won’t get connected to internet even it has signal

Tags: mac, network, wifi

My MacBook Air 2018 won’t connect to the internet even I’m using the same WiFi net on all my other devices and they work well.

It started after I deleted some daemon files that were signaled as malware.

Before that everything worked fine and I’ve already tried everything like changing dns, Ipv-6, restarting the computer.

Please help I don’t Know what to do anymore

Comment: Please get the output of `ifconfig -a` and `netstat -r` (both entered in Terminal.app) and add it to your question by [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/391800/edit) it.

Comment: The malware probably edited some of your network settings (probably so they could inject ads in your browsing), and removing the daemons didn't reset the changes. If you know the specific malware involved, you might be able to look up what changes it makes.

Answer (score 1):

Final solved the issue after tweaking every possible setup in my Mac. Somehow the proxy SOCKS was enabled and by default denying all SSL certifications.

Still don’t know how it was enabled and maybe the malware that I had activated it like another user commented before.

Thanks all by the way for your comments

Answer (score 0):

You can get all official macOS system files back by restarting in Recovery mode (boot and hold CMD-R until apple appears) and reinstalling the OS from the Recovery mode app.

Your existing data files and settings will survive this reinstall and should be just as they were.

Comment: Thanks but I already tried the recovery mode  and didn’t worked. And I can’t post the terminal.app config because the Mac has no connection. Any ideas? 

Thanks all by the way. I guess my Mac will stay useless